# EXtJS 4.2 and Android browser

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have a bunch of components that I am calling setValue on, everything is working fine in all browsers except the Android web browser and google chrome for android. Has anyone seen this behavior or knows how to solve it? I don't know where to really begin.

Comment: http://www.sencha.com/products/touch

Answer (score 0):

Ok you have to enable Javascipt for the Web View as android disables JS by default due to security reasons

```
YourWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
YourWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
```

That should so the trick

if your app has secure data you probably don't want 3rd party software running JS in your app

Hope this helps

Comment: But this is a website URL. I don't have a Android application